# Typing "gnome-control-center" on terminal causes my computer to "log out" (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-20.04

By typing the command "gnome-control-center" on terminal, it causes my computer to "log out to the main page and close all my application. I have recently change my GPU to a Evga RTX 2060. Could it be that the GPU do not support the Gnome control center?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem. I need to install Ubuntu driver for Nvidia GPU by typing the follow command.

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460`

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have same problem. The root cause was NVIDIA GPU driver lost due to `sudo apt autoremove`.

If you have NVIDIA GPU and face the `gnome-*` application crash or return to Desktop Environment Login screen, you should check the NVIDIA GPU driver installation with following command.

```bash
$ sudo cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

If the output looks like as follows:

```
cat: /proc/driver/nvidia/version: No such file or directory
```

It means NVIDIA GPU driver was not installed or uninstalled due to various reasons.

In case of successful GPU dirver installation, the output of the above command should looks like as follows:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.43.04  Tue Apr 26 15:52:32 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

- RTX 3090 on Unbuntu 20.04 example output

You can checkout your NVIDIA GPU model name with following commands:

```bash
$ sudo update-pciids
$ sudo lspci -k | grep -A 3 VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 4041
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Then, you can check drivers versions supported for your GPU at  http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us

Please find name of the NVIDIA GPU driver package from NVIDIA repo. with following command:

```bash
# check your unbuntu release and save it to release var
$ release="ubuntu"$(lsb_release -sr | sed -e "s/\.//g")

# add NVIDIA repository
$ sudo apt install sudo gnupg

$ sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys "http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/"$release"/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub"

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/'$release'/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-cuda.list'

$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/'$release'/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-machine-learning.list'
$ sudo apt update

# find NVIDIA drivers 
$ sudo apt-cache search nvidia | grep -P "nvidia-driver-\d{3}" | sort -r
```

Choose your driver version and install with following command:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-XXX
```

- `XXX` should be replaced with GPU driver version.